# How to add unlock screen or use TouchID with Security in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I'm using this code Security to add a Unlock Screen in my app:

```
 self.keyChainQuery = [
        kSecClass              : kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrService        : serviceIdentifier,
        kSecAttrAccount        : accountName,
        kSecMatchLimit         : kSecMatchLimitOne]
  var extractedData: Unmanaged<AnyObject>? = nil

  let status = SecItemCopyMatching(self.keyChainQuery, &extractedData)
```

If the device has an unlock code, then use this unlock code. If the device has TouchID this detect TouchID.

How can I set the type that I want to use between TouchID and PassCode?

Thanks!

Comment: is there anyway i can improve my answer to help you?

Answer (score 2):

TouchID and the device passcode are very different from one another. TouchID is really just a more convenient means of authenticating a user without requiring them to type in a password. This password is NOT the same passcode used when unlocking the device but rather a passcode that unlocks your App. This means that if your App already has some type of authentication system in it then TouchID can be added to prevent having the user signing in manually every time.

Keychain on the other hand is what you use to store sensitive information (like the users login credentials). In Keychain you have the ability to specify the level of Security for a keychain item ([Read more here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/reference/keychainservices/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Keychain_Item_Accessibility_Constants)). One example is the `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock` constant, this means that you will only be allowed to extract the keychain information after the has been unlocked by the user. This is quite a big gotcha for those developers who implemented Background Notifications after iOS 7 and noticed that they could no longer send credentials through to the server when the device had been restarted but not yet unlocked.

To use touchID you will need an instance of `LAContext`:

```
let context = LAContext()
if( context.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics ,error:nil) {        
    //go ahead with TouchID
} else {
   //log in the user with the login UI
}
```

Don't forget, if you are supporting a deployment target of iOS 7.1 or less you need to add the appropriate availability checks (which should be inferred by the compiler):

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    //it is safe to use touchID
    let context = LAContext()
}
```

For more, try [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-integrating-touch-id--cms-21949)

Comment: LAContext.self !=nil doesn't seem right statement. As compiler complaints about LAContext.self cant be nil ever. so comparison is not allowed.

Comment: @Alix thanks! This was done a while ago, added availability checks